# Delegating Constructors in VS11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use delegate constructors in Visual Studio 2012 Update 3, but I'm getting an error:

```
$> cl.exe /EHsc /W4 /MTd .\bla.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60610.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bla.cpp
.\bla.cpp(6) : error C2614: 'Bla' : illegal member initialization: 'Bla' is not 
a base or member
```

Example source file:

```
#include <iostream> 

class Bla {
public: 
    Bla() : Bla(10) { std::cout << "bla()" << std::endl; }
    Bla(int _n) { std::cout << "bla(int): " << _n << std::endl; }
}; 


int main() 
{
    Bla b0; 
    Bla b1(10);
}
```

It seems to have [worked before](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/wkep) and is described in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/STLCCSeries6) (starting around 31:30).

Can someone tell me the status of the implementation of delegate constructors in Visual Studio 2012? Or am I doing something wrong? Maybe my **cl.exe** command? Or do I need to install some CTP compiler or something?

Comment: Or something.  It is pretty explicitly mentioned in your link, the compiler version that supports that is a CTP release.  VS2013 Preview also just recently became available, probably releases somewhere around the fall.

Comment: You need to install the Nov 2012 CTP or later. Or download the V2013 Preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or do I need to install some CTP compiler or something?

Indeed. Delegating constructors are not supported on official releases/updates of VS2012. You have to install November 2012's CTP.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) is a summary of C++11 features supported (and not supported) by VC11.

Comment: You can also download Visual Studio 2013 Preview (which is a much better implementation of C++11 features than the CTP)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I thought the features from the CTP compilers get included into the VS updates.

Comment: @JohnBandela: Not sure how much better. It seems there are ugly bugs with move semantics that were not there in the CTP (at least AFAIK). See, for instance, [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21007284/whyyy.png).

Comment: @guini: You're welcome. No, they are not included - most likely because they are not stable enough and/or may introduce breaking changes.